# Novel from a couple of decades ago dealing with wormhole powered space flight

Tags: story-identification, space-colonization

Read this novel years ago. Starts off with a one manned space flight to another solar system to do the final testing of a wormhole generator. The test was one way trip. The humans did not realize aliens lived in the system and the test wiped them out. As they died they sent a psychic message out to universe telling all aliens the humans had killed them.  Earth was dying from ecological disaster and they built ships and as they left the solar system they wiped out this system. I remember that the rest of book deals with generations of humans trying to find habitable worlds and colonizing them. But every time they grew large enough to be noticed by aliens they would be wiped out. I remember that a lot of the rituals in the training of humans in space was done through song. And every few years the humans would have an enclave and the ships would all join together in space to share. Any ideas as to title. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Similar questions, apparently describing the same book, have been asked before: [Story where stardrive test-pilot visits alien solar system and is attacked by a psychic (alien) child](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/105958) and [book about telepaths hunting humans](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/14673). If you are looking for the same book, it's [*Earth Ship and Star Song*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?12181) by [Ethan I. Shedley](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?3896), a pseudonym of [Boris Beizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boris_Beizer). Does [this cover](https://www.isfdb.org/wiki/images/5/5b/ERTHSHIPSS1979.jpg) or [this one](https://www.isfdb.org/wiki/images/c/c1/RTHSHPNDST1981.jpg) look familiar?

[This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14673/book-about-telepaths-hunting-humans/82670#82670) by @LAK provides the following quotation from the inner flap of *Earth Ship and Star Song*, edition not specified:

> The year is 2100, and mankind has destroyed the earth's ecology.
> Faced with irrefutable evidence that the end is near, the technocracy
> that governs the remnants of the human race realizes that there is no
> workable alternative but to emigrate from this "bitter lesson called
> Earth."
>
>  But there are dangers. Man must adapt for the journey, and
> must perfect the power source for his Earth Ships—a drive based on the
> controlled creation of black holes in space. Blind to the existence of
> any sentient race that has not developed along technological lines,
> man destroys a telepathic race while refining the Black Hole Drive.
> Realizing its doom, this race spreads a call for revenge throughout
> the galaxy. The reader will follow with fascination as man—the
> hunted—tries time and again to found a new home, only to be destroyed
> and driven to the fringes of a hostile universe by increasingly
> virulent attacks. Will man be allowed to atone, or must he strike back
> to regain his place in the cosmos?

Comment: That is the book! Thank you very much!